# Skype on Windows 7 has greyed out Call button

Tags: windows-7, skype, call, skype-out

I have the latest Skype installed on my Windows 7 machine, and have been able to start it up and log in.

However, when I type in a phone number, the program was able to detect the country code and seem to parse out the number, but the green Call button is greyed out.

I have sufficient funds in my account, what could be the problem?

Comment: What does your Skype's status say? Is it "Offline"?

Comment: @Isxek Aha! It was offline when I thought I was just invisible: Skype shows the same icon for both. Thanks so much!